# How do I get this "Share" button to grab the current URL's HTML title in addition to URL?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, bookmarklet, share

I'm a JavaScript novice trying to build a basic share button as a learning project.  I'm a bit stumped about one aspect.  While I can grab the URL of the current page and pass that into the URL that prepopulates the share form, I'm not sure how to grab the HTML title.

Here's what I have to far:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.example.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false;"> Share This </a>
```

What do I add to the `onclick` section to get the current page's title as well?  Whatever it is would be passed as `title=` in the URL.

Bonus: Is there something I can add to send along some highlighted text from the current page?  That would go in the URL as `body=`

So I'm looking to fill in these blanks:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.example.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false; + 'title=' + SOMETHING + 'body=' + SOMETHING'"> Share This </a>
```

At least I think so.  I'm not 100% sure I've got the +'s and ''s in the right place.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should be aware that internet explorer has a limit on the length of a URL it can browse to.  That limit is 2048 and if the URL + title is more than that, some trimming would take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [document.title](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.title).  Getting selected text is a bit more complicated, especially if you want to support IE.  DOM standard is [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) but for IE you have to mess around with [ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533041%28VS.85%29.aspx) - I've not checked if things have improved in IE8.

Also I meant to ask, where will the share button be?  If it's in the page then clicking on the button is going to de-select the text which is selected.

Comment: This would be an HTML button anyone could drop into their blog to let them "submit" it to my generic Digg-clone's submission form. I thought making a button like this would be a solid learning project.

Comment: OK, then I think there would be a problem with text getting deselected as the user clicks the button.  You may be able to work something out by finding an adjacent text element and selecting that, but you may end up having to implement different buttons for different types of blog.

It could work if you implemented it as a bookmarklet rather than a button.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the selected text, and different browsers implement different ones:

First, there's `document.getSelection()`, which returns the selected text as a string. Then, there's `window.getSelection()`, which will return a selection object. To get the raw text, use its `toString()` method. The IE way of getting the text uses ranges, ie `document.selection.createRange().text`.

I'd suggest use of a wrapper-function to make `document.getSelection()` available for all browsers which support any of the methods mentioned above:

```
if(typeof document.getSelection === 'undefined') {
    document.getSelection =
        window.getSelection ? function() {
            return window.getSelection().toString();
        } :
        document.selection ? function() {
            return document.selection.createRange().text;
        } :
        null;
}
```

As a side note: You should set `location.href` (and not `location`) to change the document's address.